# Converting/Adopting Layouts to use 320x568 in iOS 6.0 on 4-inch iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

Calls to applicationFrame are returning 320x480 when hooked up to 4-inch iphone simulator. Is that what is preventing my layout from using the full 568? What do I have to do to eliminate the black bars from my layout?

Comment: I think this is still under NDA...

Comment: Every developer signs a NDA when downloading pre-release software. We are not allowed to help you until the software is available to anyone. But your question is already answered on stackoverflow, just use the search.